# Div-table с прокрутркой

Tags: css, html

Создал таблицу из div-ов.
Все пытаюсь сделать, чтобы таблица была на всю ширину, а у столбцов была фиксированная ширина, и если они не вмещаются то появляется scroll. overflow на .table, почему-то не действует, и колонки всегда масштабируются. Как это можно сделать?

HTML:

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">
            sd
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
            sd2
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
            sd3
        </div>
        <div class="cell">
            sd4
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.table {
    display: table;
}

.row {
    display: table-row;
}

.cell {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавил `min-width` для `.cell`

http://jsfiddle.net/zsntzugn/1/

Comment: да, действительно. минимальную ширину надо было. Спасибо. 

http://jsfiddle.net/zsntzugn/2/